# psycopg2 close connection pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, psycopg2

I'm developing a Flask API, and I have the following code to have a connection pool using Psycopg2. I wonder should I consider to close the connection pool when the program terminates and how should I do this?

```
@contextmanager
def get_cursor(:
    global connection_pool
    if not cls.connection_pool:
        cls.connection_pool = ThreadedConnectionPool(5, 25, dsn=PoolingWrap.generate_conn_string())

    con = cls.connection_pool.getconn()
    try:
        yield con.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
    finally:
        cls.connection_pool.putconn(con)
```

Comment: Before going for an answer, I'd like to know if there's a reason you aren't using sqlalchemy, which has ways that help you handle this.

Comment: what server are you using?

Comment: I agree with @LuisOrduz, SQLAlchemy is the recommended ORM for db querying in Flask. The library Flask-SQLAlchemy is well documented.

Comment: you may need to return **con** object also, after cursor.execute you have to do commit by using **con** object, after calling commit function you must put away the connection

Comment: This has nothing to do with Flask or SQLAlchemy. The general question is whether the connection_pool needs to be closed in any way and whether it can be done safely.

Comment: @mart1n - have you tried using 'with'? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

Comment: @LuisOrduz there are plenty of reasons why people justifiably choose not to use an ORM. If you don't want an ORM, using sqlalchemy is a lot of bloat just to get connection pooling.

Comment: @ScottSkiles "unlike file objects or other resources, exiting the connection’s with block doesn’t close the connection but only the transaction associated with it" The with block will close cursor objects, but not connections, and this question is about connection pools. The method to call is `closeall()` if you really want to close connections, otherwise they will eventually be deleted by GC. There's no need to worry about the pool object itself http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement

Answer (score 7):

I believe that so long as you are closing the transactions in each connection correctly, then you should not have any problem just leaving the global pool.
I think the worst that can happen in that case is some connections on the DB side take a short while to work out that they've been closed on the client side - but this should not be able to cause any data consistency type issues.

However, if you really want to close the connection pool before you exit, one way to do this is to register an `atexit` function.

```
import atexit

@atexit.register
def close_connection_pool():
    global connection_pool
    connection_pool.closeall()
```

Comment: I think `.close()` will forcefully close any existing connections even if they are processing a transaction. Is there any way to wait for those connections to be closed by themselves (or forcefully after some timeout period) and only then exit?

Comment: @mart1n There may be ways to do that, but an "atexit" handler is only called once your program is shutting down. At that stage, everything should be done. You should probably be handling that kind of logic at a higher level - before your main thread(s) exit.

Comment: Does pool have a close method? http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/pool.html I don't see it. The docs say "This pool class is mostly designed to interact with Zope and probably not useful in generic applications" eek. It's a client-side container for connections, so whether or not to close the connections seems more pertinent than closing the `pool`. `pool` does have a `closeall()` method, if really necessary, but exactly as you've said it won't be an issue because the connection objects will be deleted by GC and the server will at worst take a short while to work that out.

Comment: @Davos - you're right its `closeall` - I've updated it. Thanks.

Comment: @Davos - I read the comments about Zope as pertaining only to the `PersistentConnectionPool` subclass, not the `ThreadedConnectionPool` or `SimpleConnectionPool`.